Has anyone seen PDE involving determinant of Hessian?
Travelling through long and convoluted mathematical tracks, I have stumbled upon the following PDE. All I'm really asking is whether someone has seen this PDE before, and if it has a name. So here is the PDE:
Let $B$ be a closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly positive, continuous function. We seek a function $g \in C^2(B)$ satisfying:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
g = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{on } \partial B
\\
\det(\text{Hess } g) = f \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{in } B
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Note that this is a fully non-linear second-order PDE. Anyway, any information would be useful.

This equation is called the Monge-Ampere equation.
